# dedicated server windows 2003 with HELM, or 2008R2 64 without

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, dedicated-server

Thinking about getting a new dedicated server, having played with a shared solution and not very happy with it I am going to go back to dedicated

For the same amount of money I can get either a windows 2003 32bit server that comes with the helm control panel, versus windows 2008R2 64bit without the helm control panel (not supported)...

Question 1: Which OS is better for running asp.net web applications and some using small SQL Server database (yes, on the same machine). I assume the 64Bit will perform better...will I notice any problems with 64Bit, R2?

Question 2: How much will I miss having helm? I assume I can do manually everything helm does for me, correct? Any big drawbacks of this way? Last time I used helm, I vaguely remember not really using or needing many of the features anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the 2008 box.

- It's newer tech
- 64bit = good
- While Helm is one of the more stable packages I've used, nothing beats being able to control it yourself! (IMHO)
- 2008/IIS7 supports much of your app environment out of the box, or with minor tweaks